# Spring Security LDAP - No UserDetailsService registered

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-security

I'm trying to set up the LDAP Spring Security. And I've stucked with some strange exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_filterChainList'
...
No UserDetailsService registered
```

My security-config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">

    <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" />

    <sec:http auto-config="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" filters="none" />

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" method="POST" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/uzivatel/registrace" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_UZIVATEL" />

        <sec:form-login default-target-url="/vlakna" login-page="/login"  />
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.vote.ConsensusBased">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="rightsAccessDecisionVoter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://111.111.111.111"/>
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=auth-user,ou=System,dc=sh,dc=company,dc=com"/>
        <property name="password" value="secret"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <sec:custom-authentication-provider/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.authenticator.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
                <property name="userSearch">
                    <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                      <constructor-arg index="0" value="ou=People,dc=sh,dc=company,dc=com"/>
                      <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
                      <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list><value>uid={0},ou=people</value></list>
                </property>
                <property name="userAttributes">
                    <list><value></value></list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="cz.rohan.dusps.services.UzivatelAuthoritiesPopulator" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rightsAccessDecisionVoter" class="com.company.RightsAccessDecisionVoter" />
</beans>
```

I thought that it should take "ldapAuthProvider" as an user details service but it doesn't. Does anybody see any problem in my config?

Thanks for any help,
Mateo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think...

```
<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
<security:custom-authentication-provider />
// MISSING ABOVE
<property name="userDetailsService" ref="ldapUserDetailsService" />
.....
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me:-( I think I have to register this bean somehow outside but I don't know how:-/

Comment: you are missing the userDetailsService bean i do not see it in your configuration

Comment: You are right, I've forgot to add this code: <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.company.services.DuspsUserDetailService" /> But anyway, thanks for help!!!:-)