# Spring LDAP exception - No UserDetailsService registered

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I am trying to use Spring Security 3.0.2 LDAP authentication for a JSF website. When I use the below configuration in applicationContext-security.xml I get this exception - **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.**

```
<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=users,ou=system"
        group-search-base="ou=groups,ou=system">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://localhost:10389"
    root="" />
```

I just experimented and found that adding the below makes things work.

```
<ldap-user-service server-ref="ldapServer" user-search-filter="(uid={0})" />
```

But I could not find references to this in the [Spring LDAP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html). Why do I get the above exception if I do not add this? I am not happy with this workaround as I need to write user-search-filter attribute at two places.

**PS**: I have checked [Spring Security LDAP - No UserDetailsService registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053812/spring-security-ldap-no-userdetailsservice-registered). There the exception is different and I guess the Spring Security version is different as well.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you have `<remember-me/>` set later in the security context. As per documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me

> If you are using an authentication provider which doesn't use a
>   UserDetailsService (for example, the LDAP provider) then it won't work
>   unless you also have a UserDetailsService bean in your application
>   context.